# Checking for inconsistent values within groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the following table

```
 document_id    group_id    level
 --------------------------------
 1              1           1
 2              1           1
 3              2           3
 4              2           3
 5              2           2
 6              3           1
 7              4           6
 8              4           6
 9              4           6
10              5           2
11              5           1
```

I would like to check if the `level` of documents within one `group_id` is consistent, and if not, display those groups. So for the above example the output would have to be:

```
 document_id    group_id    level
 --------------------------------
 3              2           3
 4              2           3
 5              2           2
10              5           2
11              5           1
```

How can I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `EXISTS` to find these rows where same group_id has inconsistent level values:

```
select document_id, group_id, level
from tablename t1
where exists (select 1 from tablename t2
              where t2.group_id = t1.group_id
                and t2.level <> t1.level)
```

And this is how it executes:

```
SQL>create table t (document_id int, group_id int, level int);
SQL>insert into t values( 1, 1, 1);
SQL>insert into t values( 2, 1, 1);
SQL>insert into t values( 3, 2, 3);
SQL>insert into t values( 4, 2, 3);
SQL>insert into t values( 5, 2, 2);
SQL>insert into t values( 6, 3, 1);
SQL>insert into t values( 7, 4, 6);
SQL>insert into t values( 8, 4, 6);
SQL>insert into t values( 9, 4, 6);
SQL>insert into t values(10, 5, 2);
SQL>insert into t values(11, 5, 1);
SQL>select document_id, group_id, level
SQL&from t t1
SQL&where exists (select 1 from t t2
SQL&              where t2.group_id = t1.group_id
SQL&                and t2.level <> t1.level);
document_id    group_id       level
=========== =========== ===========
          3           2           3
          4           2           3
          5           2           2
         10           5           2
         11           5           1

                  5 rows found
```

Same result as specified in question.

Comment: this only returns the deviating rows. I was looking for the full inconsisten group to be displayed. upvote for helping me out though!

Comment: @Pr0no, I don't get your comment. My query returns the same result as you have specified.

Comment: My bad. I forgot in the OP...many times, `level` will be `NULL`. If there is a group with documents that have `NULL`, these should also be displayed. By coincidence, @Gordons answer returns this result. Agreed, it was not in the specification. Took away the accepted answer. However, how would your solution look like to also display NULLs?

Comment: I don't mind you accepting Gordon's answer. But if you want my version also, why don't you edit your question and add some nulls?

Answer (score 1):

Modified jarlh's answer to make query result match OP's desired output:

Use EXISTS to find these rows where same group also has another levels:

```
select document_id, group_id, level
from tablename t1
where exists (select 1 from tablename t2
              where t2.level <> t1.level
                and t2.group_id = t1.group_id)
```

Comment: not intending to hijack but the edit sugesstion was rejected

Comment: this only returns the deviating rows. I was looking for the full inconsisten group to be displayed. upvote for helping me out though!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `exists`, you can use window funtions:

```
select document_id, group_id, level
from (select t.*, min(level) over (partition by group_id) as minlevel,
             max(level) over (partition by group_id) as maxlevel
      from t
     ) t
where minlevel <> maxlevel;
```

Comment: marking this answer as correct one as this one returns the full groups, instead of the deviating rows :)